# rotate animation + elevation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a simple app that flips a button when it's clicked.
When the button has some elevation, the animation stutters badly and theres this line on LogCat:

> W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: adg, destroying layer...

What is really interesting is that when I turn on on-screen GPU profiling the animation runs well.

[gpu_prof_off](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7p97RiAOcwuRkt3aHlIb0I3ZXM/view?usp=sharing)
[gpu_prof_on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7p97RiAOcwubjdZYjBrdHd3U0U/view?usp=sharing)

The button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="a Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>
```

The code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    v.animate().rotationX(90).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setRotationX(-90);
            v.animate().rotationX(0).start();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

This is running on a Nexus 5 with AOSP 5.0.1.

Can anybody explain what's happening?

Comment: Interesting @jakk, I'm not getting any animation problems, but saw this in my logcat and was curious as to what it was, my searching led me here........did you manage to find out anything?  Nexus 10 running 5.0.1 BTW.

Comment: Actually I have a similar issue in an application I work on, but there I don't use shadows. I would like to figure out what causes the stuttering there, then I'm gonna file a bug report probably.